# After page refresh tab rows gets extra white space in Angular app

Tags: css, angularjs, html

I have this [app](http://lodamtest93-env.elasticbeanstalk.com/mobile/#/) where user can see a list of some devices. When clicking on a device, a details page is presented:

[image]

But when a refresh is performed on the page, there is an extra white space in the tab.

[image]

Comment: Can you post us your code too please.

Comment: And you want to get rid of the whitespace? Or what exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem get solved after adding `display:inline-block` below css.

```
.unit_details .alarm-text {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 21px;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I'm still searching why float:right is not working only after refresh!!!

Please explain anyone knows.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the Mode grid with div like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="alarm-text ng-scope" ng-if="mode==1">Heat</div>
    <img src="./images/mode_heat.svg" ng-if="mode==1" class="ng-scope">
</div>
```

I think it should be ok.